# Calling provable_query via Ethereum-bridge work only the first time

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, provable

I implemented a contract to call a api via provable and ethereum-bridge on a private ethereum. In the first time, when calling a api, it works fine. However, when tring to call api again, I got an error. I needed to deploy a new contract, then it would work only first time.

Constructor

```
constructor () payable public {
        OAR = OracleAddrResolverI(0xC7E23C5c09AD7B55d25Ca7086AA45FCa462ce171);

    }
```

Calling api

```
function updatePrice() payable public {
        provable_query("URL", "json(https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker).price");
   }
```

Provable code

```
function provable_query(string memory _datasource, string memory _arg) provableAPI internal returns (bytes32 _id) {
        uint price = provable.getPrice(_datasource);
        if (price > 1 ether + tx.gasprice * 200000) {
            return 0; // Unexpectedly high price
        }
        return provable.query.value(price)(0, _datasource, _arg);
    }
```

Error

```
errors.js:63 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xdb7c30bd168f828a7d580381653f022eafaec91b6a074655a830e938bb3b3d03",
  "blockNumber": 7240,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 47064,
  "from": "0x3f4d231c61f6fbd5706920b8e3aa8ba49d42e716",
  "gasUsed": 47064,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x7d381f40b1ab31691dfa1d80bee784f9cc896c7e",
  "transactionHash": "0x2a4d5692980a88bf65c448b2b627f018f9e916835d34b89a8e2290941b1fd2d6",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "events": {}
}
    at Object.TransactionError (errors.js:63)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (errors.js:75)
    at index.js:447
```

Comment: `when trying to call api again` - How exactly are you trying? Please show your code.

Comment: @goodvibration I updated the api-calling code. In the first time I also used the same code.

Comment: What is the code of function `provable_query`?

Comment: This function is inherited from provableAPI_0.5.sol.

Comment: What is the code of `provableAPI_0.5.sol`?

Comment: @goodvibration After addding fund to the contract that call the ethereum-brige, calling to ethereum-bridge worked. However, now it has got struck at the ethereum-bridge.

Comment: 1. You did not answer my previous question. 2. What does "struck at the ethereum-bridge" even mean???

Comment: @goodvibration Here is the code of provableAPI_0.5 https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api . Ethereum-bridge got hang after receiving a message from my contract. After restarting ethereum-bridge, it works now.